# Reactive object assignment from reactive array

Tags: vuejs3, reactive, vue-composition-api

I need to assign to a reactive object a object from a reactive array inside script setup composition API, any suggestion?

Here is my code - the variable `pokemonsReactiveArr` is:

```
export let pokemonsReactiveArr = ref<IPokemon[]>([]);
```

This array after the await call it contains 4 pokemons:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import PokemonPicture from "../components/PokemonPicture.vue";
import PokemonsOptions from "../components/PokemonsOptions.vue";
import { getPokemonsOptions } from "../helpers/getPokemonOptions";
import { pokemonsReactiveArr } from "../helpers/getPokemonOptions";

let pokemons = ref<any[]>([]);
let selectedPokemon = ref<any>({});
let idPokemon = ref<number>(0);

defineExpose({ selectedPokemon });

onMounted(async () => {
  console.log(
    "array antes de llamar al helper de pokemons en Home view: ",
    pokemonsReactiveArr
  );
  await getPokemonsOptions();
  const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  idPokemon.value = rndInt;
  console.log(
    "array despues del llamar al helper de pokemons en Home view: ",
    pokemonsReactiveArr
  );
  console.log('el pokemon seleccionado es:',pokemonsReactiveArr.value[rndInt])
  console.log("pokemon seleccionado antes: ", selectedPokemon.value);
  selectedPokemon.value = pokemonsReactiveArr.value[rndInt];
  console.log("pokemon seleccionado despues: ", selectedPokemon.value);
  console.log("id del pokemon despues de la asignacion: ", idPokemon.value);
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <!--
        <h1 v-if="!selectedPokemon">Cargando pokemon...</h1>
      -->
      <div>
        <PokemonPicture :pokemonId="idPokemon" :show="true" />
      </div>
    </v-row>
    <v-row v-if="pokemons" justify="center">
      <PokemonsOptions :pokemons="pokemonsReactiveArr" />
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

When I print in console the selected Pokemon it shows a empty proxy object but after assignment is undefined, how can I achieve the desired effect?
Here I share the logic to get the array of pokemons:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import pokemonAPI from "../api/pokemonApi";
import { IPokemon } from "../interface/IPokemon";

export let pokemonsReactiveArr = ref<IPokemon[]>([]);

const getPokemons = () => {
  const pokemonsArr = Array.from(Array(650));
  return pokemonsArr.map((_, index) => index + 1);
};

export const getPokemonsOptions = async () => {
  const mixPokemons = getPokemons().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  await getPokemonsName(mixPokemons.splice(0, 4));
};

const getPokemonsName = async (pokemonsArr: number[]) => {
  
  pokemonsArr.forEach(async (pokemonID: number) => {
    const response = await pokemonAPI.get(`/${pokemonID}`);
    pokemonsReactiveArr.value.push({ name: response.data.name, id: response.data.id });
  });
};
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend using {{obj}} to debug objects, it shows the json

Comment: Erm, can you just use computed?

Comment: I don't think reactivity will survive across imports like that. Instead You should try having `getPokemonOptions()` return the value and use that inside your component.

Comment: I proved imported reactive variables in other projects and it works fine I think that's not the problem

Comment: @francesco14 Your code should work fine. As `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)` will always return the random numbers from `0-3` and as you said `pokemonsReactiveArr` will always contain 4 elements and it is reactive. So it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I managed to get the behavior that I wanted through this code:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import pokemonAPI from "../api/pokemonApi";
import { IPokemon } from "../interface/IPokemon";

export let pokemonsReactiveArr = ref<IPokemon[]>([]);
export let pokemonSelected = ref<IPokemon>({ id: 0, name: "" });

const getPokemons = () => {
  const pokemonsArr = Array.from(Array(650));
  return pokemonsArr.map((_, index) => index + 1);
};

export const getPokemonsOptions = async () => {
  const mixPokemons = getPokemons().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  await getPokemonsName(mixPokemons.splice(0, 4));
};

const getPokemonsName = async (pokemonsArr: number[]) => {
  pokemonsArr.forEach(async (pokemonID: number) => {
    const response = await pokemonAPI.get(`/${pokemonID}`);
    if (pokemonsReactiveArr.value.length == 4) {
    } else {
      pokemonsReactiveArr.value.push({
        name: response.data.name,
        id: response.data.id,
      });
      if (pokemonsReactiveArr.value.length == 4) {
        pokemonSelected.value =
          pokemonsReactiveArr.value[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And in the HomewView.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import PokemonPicture from "../components/PokemonPicture.vue";
import PokemonsOptions from "../components/PokemonsOptions.vue";
import { getPokemonsOptions } from "../helpers/getPokemonOptions";
import {
  pokemonsReactiveArr,
  pokemonSelected,
} from "../helpers/getPokemonOptions";
import { IPokemon } from "../interface/IPokemon";
import { useGeneralStore } from "../stores/GeneralStore.ts";

const store = useGeneralStore();

let showDialog = ref<boolean>();
let answerMessage = ref<string>();
let showVictory = ref<boolean>(false);
let done = ref<boolean>(false);

onMounted(async () => {
  await getPokemonsOptions();
});

async function checkRespuesta(pokemonClicked: IPokemon) {
  if (pokemonSelected.value === pokemonClicked) {
    store.acierto();
    answerMessage.value = "¡Has acertado!";
    showDialog.value = true;
    showVictory.value = true;
    done.value = true;
  } else {
    store.reiniciaJuego();
    answerMessage.value = "¡Has fallado!";
    showDialog.value = true;
    showVictory.value = false;
    done.value = true;
  }
}

function cerrar() {
  showDialog.value = false;
}

async function reiniciar() {
  pokemonsReactiveArr.value = [];
  pokemonSelected.value = { id: 0, name: "" };
  showVictory.value = false;
  done.value = false;
  await getPokemonsOptions();
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-container>
    <template v-if="done">
      <v-row justify="center">
        {{ answerMessage?.toLocaleUpperCase() }}
      </v-row>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-text-field
            v-if="showVictory"
            color="black"
            single-line
            variant="solo-filled"
            readonly
          >
            <h2>{{ pokemonSelected.name }}</h2>
          </v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <PokemonPicture :pokemonId="pokemonSelected.id" :show="showVictory" />
      </v-row>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-btn @click="reiniciar">Reiniciar</v-btn>
      </v-row>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <h1 v-if="!pokemonSelected">Cargando pokemon...</h1>

        <div v-else>
          <div v-if="pokemonSelected.id != 0">
            <h1>¿Quién es este pokemon?</h1>
            <PokemonPicture
              :pokemonId="pokemonSelected.id"
              :show="showVictory"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-row>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <PokemonsOptions
          :pokemons="pokemonsReactiveArr"
          @pokemonmClickado="checkRespuesta($event)"
        />
      </v-row>
    </template>

    <v-dialog v-model="showDialog" persistent width="auto">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          {{ answerMessage }}
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle> tienes {{ store.getPoints }} punto/s </v-card-subtitle>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-row justify="center">
            <v-btn @click="cerrar">OK</v-btn>
          </v-row>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I hope this'd be util for someone

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never define a ref outside of a Vue component, which you are doing here:

```
// external JS file
export let pokemonsReactiveArr = ref<IPokemon[]>([]);
```

It's not good practice to do this and actually goes against the purpose of modularity and reactivity with Vue. Your refs should stay in your Vue components. Only API calls, global constants (i.e. client secret, etc.), utility, and so on should be imported in from outside JS files.

You should be defining the fetch of data in your parent component instead (which holds PokemonPicture and PokemonOptions) and setting its value in *onMounted*:

```
const pokemonsReactiveArr = ref<IPokemon[]>([]);

onMounted(() => {
    pokemonAPI.getAllPokemon(response => {
        pokemonsReactiveArr.value = response.data;
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Also as a side note, it's better to use **const** over **let** when defining refs in Vue for general practice [as shown here in their example](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref).